# Passing multiple string parameters to Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to pass some string parameters to a jQuery function in my page. My jQuery looks something like this

```
   function showModal(text1, text2, text3) {
        $('#modal1').text(text1);
        $('#modal2').text(text2);
        $('#modal3').text(text3);
        $('#modal').modal('toggle');
    }
```

And the line that's calling the function looks something like this

```
<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" var="text1"
                            text="${obj1.text}"/>
            <spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" var="text2"
                            text="${obj1.text2}"/>
            <spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" var="text3"
                            text="${obj1.text3}"/>    

<tr onclick="showModal('${text1}, ${text2}, ${text3}');">
```

I get an error in chrome when I click the table row

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes in this line:

```
<tr onclick="showModal('${text1}, ${text2}, ${text3}');">
```

are delimiting a string, so that you're only passing one argument to the function. Try:

```
<tr onclick="showModal('${text1}', '${text2}', '${text3}');">
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: Be sure to accept this answer if it solved your problem @BrijParel.